# Run bat file from java

Tags: java, batch-file

I need to run bat file from java. this is code which i used for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\test\\test.bat");
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }      
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

this code work fine. But if i add waiting code for the bat file program wait and never end. This is the bat file.

```
@echo off
echo harshana
echo harshana
echo harshana
choice /d y /t 5 > nul
echo Times up! Here I go again...
echo harshana10
```

when i run this bat file in cmd, it echo 3 time 'harshana' and wait 5 seconds. then echo the rest. but when i run the bat file from java code, that 'Times up! Here I go again...' and 'harshana10' doesn't print and java code didn't exit(waiting). How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Check if test.bat is still running, waitfor will result in the current thread  waiting untill the executed process has terminated. try exitValue() method instead of waitfor

Comment: when i run the bat file from cmd i'll terminate immediate after 5 seconds.

Comment: exitValue() also doesn't work.

Comment: Why did you add "waitFor();", you do not need. If the bat exits our main() will finish aswell. Because reader.readLine() is blocking until the connection cancels.

Comment: i added it because program should end after the process is finished,

Comment: It will finish. I tried your code (expect the .bat, because it only (choice /d y /t 5 > nul) runs on 32bit, but i adjust the code for 64bit) and it worked for me....

Comment: what did u do for adjust the code for 64bit ?